# Creating Variable Table Rows of Form Controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dataset

Coming from a primarily PHP and Javascript background, I'm used to either creating low-level functions that deal directly with writing HTML, or with declarative libraries like React which allow you to declare the structure of the HTML based on data, and then fill it in with data.

Now I'm working with ASP.NET, and I'm trying to do things more the ".NET way" instead of just following the same patterns I'd use in other frameworks.

### Objective:

Create a table with 10 rows by default. Each of these rows contains textboxes that the user will enter student data into. They can add more rows if they see fit. This data is not tied to a database or anything else, it will just be used to populate an e-mail.

### My First Attempt:

Originally I tried creating a `DataSet` with a defined schema matching what would be input.

```
studentData = New DataSet()
studentData.Tables.Add()

studentData.Tables(0).Columns.Add("StudentID")
studentData.Tables(0).Columns.Add("StudentName")
studentData.Tables(0).Columns.Add("StudentGrade")
studentData.Tables(0).Columns.Add("ContactPhone")
```

On Init I would add 10 rows to the form, and bind the data to the GridView

```
For index As Integer = 1 To ViewState("StudentCount")
    tblStudents.Rows.Add(GetTableRow(index))
Next

grdStudents.DataSource = studentData
grdStudents.DataBind()
```

The GridView is declared like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdStudents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Id#">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="studentId" Value='<%# Eval("StudentId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last/First Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="studentName" Value='<%# Eval("StudentName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grade">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="studentGrade" Value='<%# Eval("StudentGrade") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone #">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="phone" Value='<%# Eval("ContactPhone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

#### The Problem

So this gave me the form I wanted in a nice declarative fashion, which is what I wanted. However, as much as I tried different things, the data would never persist to the DataSet. I tried storing the DataSet in the session, to no avail. I changed `Eval` to `Bind`, didn't work.

The data persists in the `TextBox`s when I only call `grdStudents.DataBind()` when there is no postback, but that doesn't do too much for me; I'd like the data to make it's way back into the DataSet. I get why it's happening: if it's the data never goes back into the DataSet, calling DataBind will always bind the controls to empty data all over again.

Pretty much everything I researched online regarding DataSets and updating them always mentioned them having a backing database to update. I had no database, this is simply a local form I'm trying to generate. Maybe I was barking up the wrong tree, so I changed my approach.

### My Current Solution:

My current solution is just to manually create everything.

I start out with the base table structure in ASP:

```
<asp:Table runat="server"ID="tblStudents" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow CssClass="text-center">
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="10%">Student Id #</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="20%">Last/First Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="5%">Grade</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Width="15%">Phone #</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

And I just create the controls manually

```
' GetCellForControl is a little helper function which just puts a control in a cell and gives you the cell
Protected Function CreateTableRow(ByVal index As Integer)
            Dim row As TableRow = New TableRow

            row.Cells.Add(GetCellForControl(New TextBox With {.ID = "StudentId_" & index,  .MaxLength = 10}))
            row.Cells.Add(GetCellForControl(New TextBox With {.ID = "StudentName_" & index }))
            row.Cells.Add(GetCellForControl(New TextBox With {.ID = "StudentGrade_" & index, .MaxLength = 3}))
            row.Cells.Add(GetCellForControl(New TextBox With {.ID = "Phone_" & index, .TextMode = TextBoxMode.Phone}))

            Return row
        End Function

'In Page_Load
 For index As Integer = 1 To ViewState("StudentCount")
            tblStudents.Rows.Add(CreateTableRow(index))
        Next
```

So this works nice. To retrieve the data I can either loop through each `TableRow` and pull the controls out of each of their respective `TableCell`s, or I can just use the predictable ID's of each control to pull the data.

#### The "Problem"

Well this approach is fucntioning properly so there is no *real* problem, but I feel like I'm missing something. I'm new to ASP and .NET programming in general so there are a lot of capabilities out there that I know I don't know yet. So I'm hoping to gain insight into the functionality that can solve this problem in a more idiomatic way.

I have created other forms so far using the declarative style of tieing a GridView to DataSet, but most of those involved a backing database for the DataSet. In this case, it's just a series of identical inputs in rows that can happen between 10 and n times. It seems so simple, right? And my current solution is simple. But to me it's only the next step up from hard-coding 10 rows and inputs, there must be something better!

I feel that my first attempt was getting close to what I wanted, but I just don't know exactly what is needed to make everything click.

**Is there a way to meet the objective using a declarative approach in ASP.NET?**

*TL;DR*: I suck at ASP.NET and I'm trying to gradually suck less by understanding the idiomatic approach to solving problems in the .NET way rather than from other frameworks I'm used to or naive imperative ways.

Comment: tl;dr goes at the *beginning*, or we have to read everything to get to it! : ) [Actually, what you have there is not a tl;dr, it's more like a P.S., so it's fine where it is.]

Answer (score 1):

[This article might help](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c19e8/dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-in-gridview-and-saving/). He eventually uses a database, but you might be able to use some of his code to simply save the grid-data to a datatable and then use it as needed.

Btw, a dataset contains built-in methods for retrieving, updating and deleting to/from a db, so a dataset is not required if you're not using a database; a datatable should suffice. Hth.